# Add property to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have an array of objects as shown below

```
Object {Results:Array[2]}
     Results:Array[2]
[0-1]
0:Object
       id=1     
       name: "Rick"
1:Object
       id=2     
       name:'david'
```

I want to add one more property named Active to each element of this array of Objects.

The final outcome should be as follows.

```
Object {Results:Array[2]}
     Results:Array[2]
[0-1]
0:Object
       id=1     
       name: "Rick"
       Active: "false"
1:Object
       id=2     
       name:'david'
       Active: "false"
```

Can someone please let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 238, accepted):

You can use the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to execute a provided function once for each element in the array. In this provided function you can add the `Active` property to the element.

```
Results.forEach(function (element) {
  element.Active = "false";
});
```

Answer (score 462):

Use `Array.prototype.map()`

```js
Results.map(obj => ({ ...obj, Active: 'false' }))
```

[Read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more information.

Comment: only supported in ES6

Comment: ES5 to be precise ;) - but babel will happily decompile it

Comment: map should return a new array not mutate the object, in this case forEach would be better, or use map and return a new object `Results.map(obj=> ({
...obj,    
Active : 'false'   
}))`

Comment: Great solution @adrianolsk, you should submit that as a separate answer.

Comment: much better solution than the accepted one.

Answer (score 16):

With ES6 you can simply do:

```
 for(const element of Results) {
      element.Active = "false";
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

I came up against this problem too, and in trying to solve it I kept crashing the chrome tab that was running my app. It looks like [the spread operator for objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666433/node-5-10-spread-operator-not-working) was the culprit.

With a little help from adrianolsk’s comment and sidonaldson's answer above, I used [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) the output of the spread operator from babel, like so:

```
this.options.map(option => {
  // New properties to be added
  const newPropsObj = {
    newkey1:value1,
    newkey2:value2
  };

  // Assign new properties and return
  return Object.assign(option, newPropsObj);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use map or foreach to do that.
There are many answers with foreach so I will be telling about how to do it with map.

```
  let new_array=array.map(function(ele){
       
       return {...ele,Active:'false'};
     })
```

If you dont want to have a new array and instead mutate it you can use foreach.But if you want to mutate it with map as you are stubborn like me,you can do that by:

```
array.map(function(ele){
       
       return ele.Active='false';
     });
```

Answer (score 5):

```
  Object.defineProperty(Results, "Active", {value : 'true',
                       writable : true,
                       enumerable : true,
                       configurable : true});
```

Comment: Defining a dynamic property using Object.defineProperty.

Answer (score 5):

It goes through the object as a key-value structure. Then it will add a new property named 'Active' and a sample value for this property ('Active) to every single object inside of this object. this code can be applied for both array of objects and object of objects.

```
   Object.keys(Results).forEach(function (key){
            Object.defineProperty(Results[key], "Active", { value: "the appropriate value"});
        });
```

Comment: Yes sure, It goes through the object as a key-value structure. Then it will add a new property called 'Active' and a sample value to every single object inside of this object. this code can be applied for both array of objects and object of objects.

Answer (score 0):

for (let i = 0 ; i < 9999 ; i ++) {
const blastMe = document.getElementById('pcBlaster');
blastMe.innerHtml = `<span>Bye ${i} blasterss </span>`
}

// output = :) | ==> You will test and reply.... , Good Luck

Comment: are you sure this answer related to question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).