# forEach/map on array of objects does not add properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

I have an array of objects in them. I want to add two new properties to all objects in that array.
The objects position in the array and the length of the array.

my code for this is:

```
 objArr.forEach(function(element) {
        element.data.basics.all= objArr.length, 
        element.data.basics.position= objArr.indexOf(element), 
    });
```

While in the forEach-loop the properties are added. I can print them while beeing in the loop. But after the loop has finished the properties are gone.

if have tried [Add property to an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922998/add-property-to-an-array-of-objects/38923170) but both, forEach and .map does not work.

I also tried:

```
 objArr.forEach(function(element) {
        element.data.basics.all= objArr.length, 
        element.data.basics.position= objArr.indexOf(element), 
        return element
    });
```

and

```
 objArr.map(function(element) {
   element.data.basics.position = objArr.indexOf(element)
       element.data.basics.all= objArr.length, 
        return element;
     }
 )
```

and i tried arrow function in all cases, so `...objArr.forEach((element)=>{...})

Comment: What *exactly* does "after the loop has finished" mean? What is the larger context of that `forEach`?  Also there's no need for `.indexOf(element)`; the second parameter to the `.forEach()` callback is the index into the array, so you can just use that.

Comment: **off-topic**: the second param to forEach is the index of the element, so you don't need `objArr.indexOf(element)`

Comment: Return inside `forEach` doesn't make any sense. and also things seems fine with the code you posted. you should post more code

Comment: please add `objArr`.

Comment: Using your code, and what I assume your object structure looks like, I get `{ all: 1, position: 0 }` with one element in `objArr`... `let objArr = [{
  data: {
    basics: {
      all: 0,
      position: -1
    }
  }
}]`

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with forLoop, new properties are added.

```js
var array = [
        { person: { age: 76 }, state: 'ka' },
        { person: { age: 87 }, state: 'ap' },
        { person: { age: 45 }, state: 'tn' }
    ];
    array.forEach(function(element, index){
        element.person.length = array.length;
        element.person.index = index;
    });
    console.log(array)
```