# Push element at each index in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, push, associative-array

I have an array, i wan to add one more key value pair at each index.

```
var ajaxResult = ajaxGet("URL");
    if (ajaxResult.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < ajaxResult.length; i++) {
            debugger

            ajaxResult[i].prototype.push.apply({ "selectedTripLeader": $scope.TripLeaderData[0].Id });
            debugger
        }
    }
```

I am trying to achieving * selectedTripLeader at each array item present into ajaxResult.*
e.g. array[0].push({ "selectedTripLeader": $scope.TripLeaderData[0].Id })
array[1].push({ "selectedTripLeader": $scope.TripLeaderData[0].Id })

i have tried using normal push and prototype.push but it is not working. 
Solution with for loop or for each loop will be ok

Comment: Wait. What are you exactly trying to do here?

Comment: The first argument of `apply` is the context, you can also access it as a static property. It doesn't make sense

Comment: `ajaxResult[i].selectedTripLeader = $scope.TripLeaderData[0].Id`?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to [add a new property to each object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object) in your array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add property to an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922998/add-property-to-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: The code is from the last solution i have tried, I want key-value pair at each item of the ajaxResult array. But I'm not able to push directly into ajaxResult[item]. It displaying error 'Push is not a function'

Comment: ajaxResult[i].selectedTripLeader = $scope.TripLeaderData[0].Id I'm using this to display dropdown list for each row. i.e. to assign andular model

Comment: Please add which array you are getting from API and your $scope.TripLeaderData in question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to add a property to your object, you can use the **spread operator** to merge the current object with your new property:

```
var ajaxResult = ajaxGet("URL");
  if (ajaxResult.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ajaxResult.length; i++) {
      ajaxResult[i] = {
        ...ajaxResult[i],
        selectedTripLeader: $scope.TripLeaderData[0].Id
      };
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

At an index of i in ajaxResult, its an object(ajaxResult[i]). You can't use push function on an object, you can use it on an array. To append a new key-value pair inside an existing object, you can do the following thing:

var a={};
a.name='Joe'; 
    OR 
a[name]='Joe';

Both are the ways to add new key-value pair in Object.

So in your scenario, it should be as below given code.

```
 ajaxResult[i].selectedTripLeader= $scope.TripLeaderData[0].Id
                          OR
 ajaxResult[i]['selectedTripLeader'] = $scope.TripLeaderData[0].Id
```