# How to check if there is no selected value then select first item?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to add new values inside each object in Array and if there is no selected tag then it will choose first option from drop down. The point is that there is also another function for selecting item from drop down. How can I make them work together correctly?

```
    <b-dropdown aria-role="list">
                    <b-button
                      icon-right="caret-down"
                      class="ToolbarButton"
                      size="is-small"
                    >
                      <span> isTagSelected(selectedProduct) </span>
                    </b-button>
    
                    <b-dropdownitem
                      v-for="selectedTag in selectedProduct.tags"
                      :key="selectedTag.id"
                      aria-role="listitem"
                      @click="selectTag(selectedProduct, selectedTag)"
                    >
                      {{ selectedTag.title }}
                    </b-dropdownItem>
```

**js**

```
 isTagSelected(selectedProduct) {
          if (!selectedProduct.tagTitle && selectedProduct.tags.length) {
            this.$set(selectedProduct.tags[0].id, 'tagId')
            this.$set(selectedProduct.tags[0].title, 'tagTitle')
            return selectedProduct.tagTitle
          }
    else { return selectedProduct.tagTitle}
        },

  selectTag: function(selectedProduct, selectedTag) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedProducts.length; i++) {
        if (this.selectedProducts[i].id === selectedProduct.id) {
          this.$set(this.selectedProducts[i], "tagId", selectedTag.id);
          this.$set(this.selectedProducts[i], "tagTitle", selectedTag.title);
        }
      }
    }
```

isTagSelected function throws an error that can't us in for looping in this.$set lines. How can be it fixed?

Comment: You only have two arguments in the "this.$set()" function.  What value do you want to assign to the new property?

Comment: I need to assign the first items title of the array of tags to that columnTitle if the user didn't selected yet value by the function which you gave yesterday. Also I hope it will not set the property second time

Comment: It says Cannot use 'in' operator to search for tagId

Comment: There are still a few things I'm unsure about with the code.  For example, isTagSelected() will try to return selectedProduct.tagTitle even when !selectedProduct.tagTitle is true?

Comment: Your yesterdays code works perfectly you select from dropdown and selected values are getting assigned to the new properties which later get sent to the backend. That part is fine. The issue is that before user will select that value from drop down I am trying to set initial value the first item from tags array so in case if user will not select anything the first value will be sent to the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to add props to selectedProduct.  Please let me know if this logic looks correct to you:

```
 isTagSelected(selectedProduct) {
    if (!selectedProduct.tagTitle && selectedProduct.tags.length) {
        this.$set(selectedProduct, 'tagId', selectedProduct.tags[0].id)
        this.$set(selectedProduct, 'tagTitle', selectedProduct.tags[0].title)
        return selectedProduct.tagTitle
    }
    else { 
        return selectedProduct.tagTitle}
    }
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much!!