# How to add a field to each object in array and push that result array to another array using react and javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to add a field type to each object in an array and push the result to another array and push that to another array.

below is how the array of object looks,

```
const arrObj1 = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'n1',
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'n2',
    }
]

const arrObj2 = [
    {
        id: '3',
        name: 'n3',
    },
    {
        id: '4',
        name: 'n4',
    }
]
```

**what i am trying to do?**

i want to add a type field with value 'type1' to arrObj1 and type field with value 'type2' to arrObj2

so the output should be like below,

```
const arrObj1 = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'n1',
        type: 'type1',
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'n2',
        type: 'type1',
    }
]

const arrObj2 = [
    {
        id: '3',
        name: 'n3',
        type: 'type2',
    },
    {
        id: '4',
        name: 'n4',
        type: 'type2',
    }
]
```

then i want to combine these two arrays arrObj1 and arrObj2 into one array like below

```
const combinedArrObj = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'n1',
        type: 'type1',
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'n2',
        type: 'type1',
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        name: 'n3',
        type: 'type2',
    },
    {
        id: '4',
        name: 'n4',
        type: 'type2',
    }
]
```

**what i have tried?**

```
const arrObj1Res = arrObj1.map((obj: any) => {
    return {
        ...arrObj1,
        type: 'type1',
    }
});
const arrObj2Res = arrObj2.map((obj: any) => {
    return {
        ...arrObj2,
        type: 'type2',
    }
});
const combinedArrObj = [
    ...arrObj1Res,
    ...arrObj2Res,
];
```

this works. but how can i refactor to something simple rather than adding field type for each obj in array and then combine

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: What are the criteria of determining ```type1``` and ```type2``` ? You just have two array of objects?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add property to an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922998/add-property-to-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: See also [Merge 2 arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7146217/215552)

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to do this all in one step. The best code does things in multiple, simple, understandable steps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
let result=arrObj1.concat(arrObj2)
function contains(a, obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] === obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
result.filter(element => {
      if (contains(arrObj1,element) ){
        element.type='type1'
        return element
      }else {
        element.type='type2'
        return element
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure JS, just a simple for loop can do the part where you add a field named type.

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrObj1.length; i++){
 arrObj1[i].type = "type1";
}
for(var i = 0; i < arrObj2.length; i++){
 arrObj2[i].type = "type2";
}
```

and to combine the arrays together just use concat.

```
const combinedArrObj = arrObj1.concat(arrObj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const allArrayObject = arrObj1.concat(arrObj2);


const finalResultArray = allArrayObject.reduce((finalResultArray, eachArrayObj, index) =>{
     const isTypeOne =  arrObj1.length - 1 >= index
     const relevantTypeString = isTypeOne ? "type1" : "type2"

     eachArrayObj.type = relevantTypeString
     finalResultArray.push(eachArrayObj)  
    
     return finalResultArray
}, [])
```