# How to add a method to an array of Object instances in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an array 'x' and array x has 100 instances of an object. Lets say after I made this array of instances, I wanted to add an additional method to each instance within array x, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not add the method to the object before filling the array?

Comment: Anything wrong with iterating the array and adding the method to the objects?

Comment: Use a loop to reduce the problem to “add an additional method to a single object”. Methods are just properties in JavaScript, so it’s “set a property on an object”.

Comment: duplicate: [Add property to an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922998/add-property-to-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 2):

If they are instances of some common class try this:

```js
// create a class
class Item {
  constructor() {
    this.x = Math.random() * 10 | 0;
  }
}

// create instances
const items = [...Array(100).keys()].map(() => new Item())

// add missing method
Item.prototype.print = function() {
  console.log(this.x)
}

// test added method
items.forEach(item => item.print())
```

In the other case, you can just add a function to each instance

```js
// generate objects
const items = [...Array(100).keys()].map(() => ({
  x: Math.random() * 10 | 0
}))

// add a function to each object
items.forEach(item => item.print = function() {
  console.log(this.x)
})

// test the added function
items.forEach(item => item.print())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop to iterate over the array items and assign your method to each object:

```js
x = [...];
for (var i = 0; i < x.length ; i++) {
    x[i].method = func () {...};
}
```