# Why isn't my spread syntax working in node v7.0.0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I am trying to use the Object Spread syntax like so:

```
let credentialsWithAuth =  { ...credentials, type: 'basic' }
```

Where credentials is an object with username and password as keys and values. But this blows up with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...`

So do I have to setup node with babel for this to work? I thought native support was now built in.

http://node.green/

Can't I use this without `Object.assign` etc?

Could someone please clarify?

Comment: Is this suppose to work on vanilla Node without Babel?

Comment: Yeah that's what I am wondering after looking at this http://node.green/

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36666473/3889043) answer,  the Object spread is not an official implementation of ECMAscript, yet. Only works array spread. This, for instance, would work: `credentials = [1,2]; [...credentials, 3]`. You'll have to go with `babel` or `Object.assign`, unfortunately.

Comment: **Note that the spread operator can be applied only to iterable objects:**
from msdn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spread syntax which is available in node 7.0 doesn't handle spreading properties of an object. What you're looking for is [object spread syntax](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#test-object_spread_properties) which is currently on stage 3 of TC39 Process. You can find more info about the process in the [process document](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/) and info about proposal in [its repository](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread).

Comment: Old question, but just wanted to update that node v8+ has full support for object spread. Here's the non-esnext support link https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-object_rest/spread_properties

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is only supported in node_8x and above. However the correct equivalent using `Object.assign()` (That does not overwrite the source object) is:

```js
let credentials = { username : 'test', password: 'test' }
let credentialsWithAuth = Object.assign({}, { type: 'basic' }, credentials)

console.log(credentialsWithAuth)
```